# How can I request a selected value in a combobox in ASP.net after a post?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, combobox

I have a combobox on a web form. The user can select a single value in the list. When the "Save" button is pressed, it has to send the post. Amongst the combobox are a few other controls, such as textboxes. When I try to read out the information that has been posted I can't seem to find/access the selected value of the combobox. I can, however, read out the values from the textboxes just fine.

Here's the line of code I'm using to read the information:

```
project.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(
    Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$uxCustomerComboBox$HiddenField"]);
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1**: This is how the combobox is built up (keep in mind it's inside of a table):

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="uxCategoryComboBox" 
              runat="server" 
              DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
              AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend">
```

This is how I'm trying to read the actual value of the combobox:

```
uxCategoryComboBoxId.Value = uxCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem.Value;
```

**Edit 2**: This is how we tried to read the SelectedValue using an eventhandler, whilst debugging:

```
<asp: DropDownList ID="uxCategoryComboBox" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="setIndex" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp: DropDownList>
```

This is the method `setIndex`:

```
protected void setIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _project[0].CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(uxCategoryComboBox.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Do you have ViewState enabled?

Comment: why are you accessing a hidden field? are you setting that with javascript? why not just use a server-sie combobox?

Comment: The combobox is indeed running at the server. ViewState is not currently enabled, no. I am very new to ASP.net, so please be patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use the automatically-generated control IDs (e.g. `ctl00$MainContent$uxCustomerComboBox$HiddenField`) in the code-behind, or access the `Request.Form` object. The correct way to obtain the value of a drop-down list control is through the `SelectedValue` property. So I think you should just be able to do this:

```
project.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(this.uxCategoryComboBox.SelectedValue);
```

**Edit:**

I've just realised you're using a `ComboBox` control, not the standard `DropDownList`. ComboBox isn't a standard ASP.NET control (as far as I know), so it could be that having ViewState turned off is causing this problem.

Some kind of "state" is necessary for the combo-box to be correctly populated during postbacks. The standard ASP.NET controls use `ControlState`, so that they will work to some degree when `ViewState` is turned off. It could be that this ComboBox control you're using is totally reliant on ViewState, so I'd try turning that on, either for the page as a whole or just on this control.

Comment: We tried that as well, but the value doesn't seem to change. It stays the same as before the post.

Comment: @Kevin - I'm not quite sure what you mean. What value are you trying to change? If the selected value of the drop-down list is "A", then this will be the value of `dropDownList.SelectedValue` on a postback. Are you trying to update another control with this value?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. We have in our combobox 3 values: AAA, BBB and CCC. BBB is automatically selected (read from the database, then selected) when the form loads. When we click on one of the other values, say, CCC, and read out the SelectedValue, it still says BBB is selected. This is the case before *and* after the post. I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea what.

Comment: We have enabled the `ViewState`, yet the value still doesn't change. We've enabled it on the form and on the controls itself.

Comment: @Kevin - maybe there's a bug in this ComboBox control then. Is this from some freely-available toolkit or something, or is it your own Server/User Control?

Comment: It's an AJAX ToolKit ComboBox. To make sure it wasn't that which caused our problem, we tried it with the DropDownList as well. Same problem, unfortunately. The value doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the controls are runat="server" with unique ID's, then you could just access it directly in code behind.

Comment: I tried that, maybe I'm doing it wrong though. I edited my original question to explain a little more.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to access the control by doing: uxCategoryComboBoxId.Value = uxCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem.Value;

Comment: I get no error message at all. The value isn't changed, it's still the old value from when we just loaded in the info from the database, whereas it should've been changed after the post.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that the input has some value at all? Could you verify that. Also, how do you submit the form? Do you have a button that calls some method on the code behind?

Comment: Yes, we selected an item in the ComboBox (and tried DropDownList too) and then press a button that calls the method to post all of it. But even before we post it, if we try to read the selected value from the ComboBox, it doesn't register correctly.

Comment: Have a look at **Edit 2**, I edited my question to show you how I tested it using an eventhandler.